# Delphi procedure parameter: var is slower than pointer?

Tags: performance, delphi, pointers, parameters

I've got a "send" routine in Delphi 6 that accepts a variable-sized block of data (a fixed-size header followed by varying amounts of data) and the routine eventually calls sendto() in Winsock.  I've coded it two ways, once where the passed block is a var (somewhat misleading, but it works) and once where a pointer to the block is passed.  A simple version used for benchmarking looks something like:

```
type 
  header = record destination, serialnumber: integer end;
  pheader = ^header;

var
  smallblock: record h: header; data: array[1..5] of integer end;
  bigblock: record h: header; data: array[1..100] of integer end;

procedure send1(var h: header; size: integer);
begin
h.destination := 1; // typical header adjustments before sendto()
h.serialnumber := 2;
sendto(sock, h, size, 0, client, sizeof(client))
end;

procedure send2(p: pheader; size: cardinal);
begin
p^.destination := 1;
p^.serialnumber := 2;
sendto(sock, p^, size, 0, client, sizeof(client))
end;

procedure doit1;
begin
send1(smallblock.h, sizeof(smallblock));
send1(bigblock.h, sizeof(bigblock));
end;

procedure doit2;
begin
send2(@smallblock, sizeof(smallblock));
send2(@bigblock, sizeof(bigblock));
end;
```

The "send" routine will be called often, with many different block sizes, and should be as fast as possible.  After doing a few runs of some simple benchmarks (by timing calls with gettickcount), the pointer technique (doit2) seems to run about 3% faster on my machine than the var technique (doit1), although I don't see any real difference between the two techniques in the object code (not that I'm an assembler guru).

Is the 3% an illusion due to my crude benchmarks, or is the pointer technique really beating the var technique?

Comment: @mikey: No, there isn't. :-) See my response to you in Remy's answer.

Comment: 3% is a humongous difference. Check your benchmarks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no performance difference passing a `var` parameter versus a pointer parameter.  They do exactly the same thing (pass a memory address), and compile to similar, if not identical, assembly code.  So any benchmarking differences are likely to be caused by issues in the benchmarking itself, not in the code that is being benchmarked.  `GetTickCount()` is not exactly the best benchmarking tool, for instance.  The best way to time your code is to use an external profiler, like AQTime.

BTW, your `doit2()` test should be like this instead:

```
procedure doit2;
begin
  send2(@(smallblock.h), sizeof(smallblock));
  send2(@(bigblock.h), sizeof(bigblock));
end;
```

Comment: @mikey: It's not sending `smallblock.h`. It's sending a `smallblock` record, starting at the address of `smallblock.h`. IOW, it's sending `sizeof(smallblock.h) + sizeof(smallblock.data)` bytes beginning at the address of `smallblock.h`.

Comment: OK gotcha  - it's buffer[0] - thanks - I will delete - I don't have sendto engraved in my head. :-) And that is what Remy meant. This is why I started hanging out on this site again. Been working a job for 2.5 where I don't do any of this type of work. 'Use it or lose it'. This site helps me stay sharp.


But if he's using var anyhow, maybe the way it's written up there is fine. Is @ necessary if a param is declared as var? It's a pointer anyhow.

Comment: Also, I found it to be a small difference when 1.repeating a benchmark and 2.reversing the order of tests. 3% is within this tolerance. I also saw benchmarks which had something CPU intensive calculations **before** the real test started to get a modern CPU to workload. I don't know whether this is religion or not, but from the explanation, I tend to follow this approach.